# Why does "!=LOW" != "HIGH"?

Tags: port-mapping

I'm learning about accessing ports directly on the ATMEGA 328 using an Arduino Uno. The program sets up pin 13 as an output and pin 2 as an input. I then enable the pull up resistor on pin 2.

I read Pin 2 and set the LED high or low depending on if pin 2 is high or low.

**Why is it that I cannot seem to use == HIGH in my if statement instead of != LOW?**

```
void setup() {
  MCUCR &= ~(1 << 4); //disables pull-up disable (redundant as default is off)
  DDRB |= (1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as output
  DDRD &= ~(1 << 2); //sets pin 2 (D2 on ATMEGA 328) as input (redundant as default is input)
  PORTD |= (1 << 2); //since it's an input sets pull-up resistor ON
  PORTB &= ~(1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as LOW

}

void loop() {
  if ((PIND & (1 << 2)) != LOW) PORTB |= (1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as HIGH
  else PORTB &= ~(1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as LOW
   delay(100);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
((PIND & (1 << 2)) != LOW)
```

means exactly

```
(PIND & 4) != 0
```

and that is true if PIND is 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, ... (any number having 4 in it binary), so it yelds

```
4 != 0
```

Which is definitively not equal

```
4 == 1
```

---

BTW: in C any integer != 0 is true and 0 is false, so you can as well write:

```
if (PIND & (1 << 2)) PORTB |= (1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as HIGH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((PIND & (1 << 2)) != LOW) PORTB |= (1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as HIGH
  else PORTB &= ~(1 << 5); //sets pin 13 (B5 on ATMEGA 328) as LOW
```

PIND & (1<<2) will return a value of either (1<<2) if PD.2 is high, or 0 if PD.2 is low.

So it basically says that if PD2 is high, set PB5; otherwise, clear PB5.`enter code here`

Comment: Thanks, Danny. Yeah I should have known... dork move on my part.